# javascript textarea value and if

Tags: javascript, html

I use the following code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function asd(){
            var b = document.getElementById("txt").value;
            var c = document.getElementById("txt2").value;
            if( b > c ){alert("The first value more than the second value");}
        }

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea id="txt"></textarea>
        <input type="button" value="Click me" onclick=asd()>
        <br>
        <textarea id="txt2"></textarea>
    </body>
</html>
```

But the codes work incorrectly. 
I am writing the firs textarea, 5.
I'm writng the scnd textarea , 40.
And alarm works. ı dont understand. I searched and find solution.

```
if( parseInt(b,10)) > (parseInt(c,10)) )
```

So why has failed the first time?

Comment: Initially it failed to work because the values you get from form inputs are strings.  The parseInt converts the string to a number so it can be properly compared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It failed the first time because the numbers are parsed as strings.

```
var b = document.getElementById("txt").value; //b = "5"
var c = document.getElementById("txt2").value; // c = "40"
if( b > c ){ // "5" > "40" is false because the browser will not understand this.
    alert("The first value more than the second value");
}
```

If you use parseInt the strings will be parsed as an integer.

So:

```
var b = document.getElementById("txt").value; //b = "5"
var d = parseInt(b); // d = 5
```

The 'is greater/less than' sign will only work with integers ( and floats etc.) but not with strings. That's why the if-statement returned false.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing quotation marks around the method

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function asd(){
    var b = document.getElementById("txt").value;
    var c = document.getElementById("txt2").value;
    if( b > c ){
        alert("The first value more than the second value");
    }
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="txt"></textarea>
<input type="button" value="Click me" onclick="asd()">
<br>
<textarea id="txt2"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This code won't work, you need to add `parseInt()` to b and c. Then it'll be perfect :)

Comment: Works in my chrome, not saying you're wrong though :) that should be added

Comment: @Hellmorf : adding parseInt was not your only problem, haakym also noticed you forgot quotation marks. Without these too problems fixed, it does not work in my Chrome.

Comment: :D , I played on codes, (change) but This work on my computr (chorome and IE)

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't working because you are storing a string. This is why you can't compare them correctly. You need to convert them into integer data types before you can compare them or perform arithmetic operations.

```
function asd(){
var b = document.getElementById("txt").value;
var c = document.getElementById("txt2").value;
if( parseInt(b) > parseInt(c) ){alert("The first value more than the second value");}
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

```
The parseInt function converts its first argument to a string, parses it, and returns an integer or NaN. If not NaN, the returned value will be the decimal integer representation of the first argument taken as a number in the specified radix (base). For example, a radix of 10 indicates to convert from a decimal number, 8 octal, 16 hexadecimal, and so on. For radices above 10, the letters of the alphabet indicate numerals greater than 9. For example, for hexadecimal numbers (base 16), A through F are used.

If parseInt encounters a character that is not a numeral in the specified radix, it ignores it and all succeeding characters and returns the integer value parsed up to that point. parseInt truncates numbers to integer values. Leading and trailing spaces are allowed.
```